# Maximum principle applied to the Delta "function".

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, maximum-principle

Let $\Omega\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain with a fixed $x\in \Omega$. Let $u$ be a function subject to $$\begin{cases} \Delta u=\delta (y-x),  & \forall y \in \Omega\\ u=0, & \forall y \in \partial\Omega\end{cases} $$

Prove that $u$ has a fixed sign and determine this sign.

My approach: Intuitively speaking, since $\delta$ is a nonnegative "function" inside $\Omega$, so by the maximum principle we have $u(y)<\max_{\partial\Omega} u=0$ which implies the sign is negative. However, this argument is not rigorous as $\delta (y-x)$ is a distribution rather than a function. Could anyone make my argument rigorous? I think the main part of the argument is to deal with the singularity at $y=x.$

Comment: If $\Omega$ is a ball with centre $x$, you know what $u$ is. Can you derive the general case from this?

Comment: Thanks. Of course we may do it by using fundamental solution to Laplace equation. But my aim is to prove it abstractly without any explicit solution. In fact, this result would imply that Green's function for Dirichlet problem must have a fixed sign.